# PlayConfig.getOptional NoSuchMethedError when changing my sbt to multi project

Tags: scala, playframework

I changed my play application from a normal sbt project to a multi project.
My play app compiles fine, but running it I see this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.PlayConfig.getOptional(Ljava/lang/String;Lplay/api/ConfigLoader;)Lscala/Option;
     play.api.libs.ws.WSConfigParser.parse(Config.scala:46)
     play.api.libs.ws.WSConfigParser.get(Config.scala:33)
     play.api.libs.ws.WSConfigParser.get(Config.scala:31)
     com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
```

My plugins.sbt looks like:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error with while migrating from play 2.4.x to 2.5.10.The application compiled successfully but threw the above run time error.

I updated the play - mailer from 3.0.1 to 5.0.0 and it fixed the issue for me.

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0"
```